# Video sharing across Android, IOS

Tags: android, ios, video

Objective: i) I want to play video that i captured on my android phone to IOS and vice versa.

Problem: Android captures it in mp4 while IOS plays in Mov.

Solution: I can do conversion of formats before uploading to server but thats a slow process
and causing performance issues.

Is there any library or solution that does it without slow it down?

I believe whatsapp does it by only uploading stream and making it correct format when someone requests to play it. Im not sure though how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not play the mp4 video on iOS? What need is there to convert?

EDIT: Also forgot to mention, mp4 and mov are basically the same format. You can literally just rename the extension (on iOS at least) and the video still plays.